# WPF ToolKit Datagrid :Ignore the newly added rows for sorting in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

The issue requires adding the custom sorting to the datagrid, where in it requires rows swapping based on the sort type i.e., ascending/descending. 
Since we have the datatable binded to datagrid Itemsource, not  able to get the right API’s associated with the datatable to move the rows across the datagrid unlike the IEnumerable which has API’s like ***Move*** to move the rows across different positions in the datagrid.
Tried conversion the datagrid Itemsource to ICollectionViewSource or IEnumerable, but not able to achieve what is needed.
Had refered the following link for reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72c57bc5-7181-4177-87fe-c838638777db/wpf-datagrid-sorting-add-blank-a-row-always-at-bottom-irrespective-of-sort?forum=wpf

Comment: The link to msdn you posted solved my problem. +1 for that.